# Logout MVC3 C# application with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have made an mvc3 application with Windows Authentication. Everything works fine but I can't seem to find a way to log-out. I have read that I have to use forms Authentication with AD impersonation, because I still want to access the guid from the ad. Has anyone else found a different method to do this.

Comment: Just add not sure if it helps
You can create log on using your own validation against AD 
and after than you can have log out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Javascript solution](http://blog.geniar.com/index.php/2010/03/aspnet-mvc-ad-windows-authentication-how-to-logout/) in order to do this.  Otherwise, I'm not sure that it can be done without impersonation or use the `FormsAuthentication` option.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to logout because the *Kerberos authentication will persist for all pages*.  A solution would be to use **Forms Authentication**.  Then you could easily call:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Should that be `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`?