# The application won’t logout unless browser is completely closed ASP.NET – VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I have developed an ASP.NET – VB application; everything is working fine except the log out button.

The application does not log out completely unless after log out I close the browser completely.

If I just close the tab and other tabs are still open the application will stay logged in and when a user visits the application again it will not ask for log in.

Below is my code for Log out button and web.config can you please tell me what I have change in this code.

**FYI – Active directory is use for authentication**

**Log out button**

```
Protected Sub ButtonClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonClose.Click

    Me.Session.Clear()
    Me.Session.Abandon()

    HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()
    ViewState.Clear()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
    Response.AddHeader("max-age", "1")
    Response.AddHeader("Expires", "-1")

    Response.Redirect("LogOut.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this only happening on Internet Explorer only or on other browsers as well?

Comment: @Humpy on other browsers as well. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your log in routine?

Comment: @DaiBok I am using the standard ASP.NET login widget - <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"> </asp:Login>

Comment: @DaiBok Does this answer your question or you after something else, Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a read around, this seems that this is the way windows authentication works out of the box, so you could considered a feature or limitation...

see 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1687661.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview

[Logout MVC3 C# application with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212364/logout-mvc3-c-sharp-application-with-windows-authentication)

From the link above, you could use some javascript, so maybe you could try it and see if it works? I am not show how cross browser compatible it is?

http://blog.geniar.com/index.php/2010/03/aspnet-mvc-ad-windows-authentication-how-to-logout/